# How to get a count of followers from Twitter API and trendline

Tags: twitter

I am in the process of writing some reports for the number of followers over time for Twitter, however after substantial searches and trial and error, I have not being able to get the number of followers over time - particularly past number of followers.

I know there is an API to get the individual userIds for the followers, but thats an overkill for what I need and I would have to call it everyday. Ideally it would be great if I can pass a date and it could return the number of followers.

Does anyone have any experience with this and what the API might be!

Thanks

Answer (score 39, accepted):

While there is no direct API to get the trendline, getting the followers count is fairly easy, access via the URL:

```
http://api.twitter.com/1/users/show.json?user_id=12345
```

The documentation has it all @ https://dev.twitter.com/docs/api/1/get/users/show

To get the trendline, seems like I will need to query it on a daily basis!

**Updated to Twitter API v1.1**

```
https://api.twitter.com/1.1/users/show.json?user_id=12345
```

Documentation at https://dev.twitter.com/docs/api/1.1/get/users/show

**Updated 31-May-2018**

The new API end point is at

```
https://developer.twitter.com/en/docs/accounts-and-users/follow-search-get-users/api-reference/get-users-show
```

Comment: Is this rate limited? Can someone elaborate if there's a way to get a specific users follower count without rate limitation? I noticed I can hit v1 without authentication - but that's going to be scrapped soon?

Comment: you are allowed to hit each of the api endpoints a limited number of times every 15 minutes. some endpoints allow 100 requests, others a bit more, per time window. Note this limits are per user token you own, so the number of queries allowed is fairly big.

Comment: The rate is 180/ 15 mins

Comment: When you make updates, put the most recent one on top, as it's the one newcomers will see first

Comment: Plz update it for V2

Comment: @ZedBee check my answer. :)

Comment: @Jason, I want to get the followers list for a specific Twitter user, can you please guide me, here is the question link: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76726633/get-twitter-account-followers-using-api-and-google-apps-script

Answer (score 5):

Here is a simple PHP exemple using CURL, with no library involved, to get the followers_count of a selected profile (here @TwitterFrance) using v2 API and the bearer token (bearer token is some kind of simplified method to access public data through an OAuth 2.0 API)

```
$authorization = "Authorization: Bearer YOUREXTRALONGBEARERYOUREXTRALONGBEARERYOUREXTRALONGBEARERYOUREXTRALONGBEARERYOUREXTRALONGBEARERYOUREXTRALONGBEAR";
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array('Content-Type: application/json', $authorization));
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, "https://api.twitter.com/2/users/by/username/TwitterFrance?user.fields=public_metrics");
$result = curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);
if (is_string($result)) {
    echo (json_decode($result)->data->public_metrics->followers_count);
    die();
}
```

Comment: I want to get the followers list for a specific Twitter user, can you please guide me, here is the question link: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76726633/get-twitter-account-followers-using-api-and-google-apps-script

Answer (score 5):

I know this is an old question but I want to give an answer for those who still looking for an alternative way to get Twitter followers count. After I spent some time on documentation, I found that you’ll need to apply for Elevated access via the Developer Portal, in order to get more than Essential information. You need to apply for additional access within the developer portal for this access level. You can check Access Levels from here.

https://developer.twitter.com/en/docs/twitter-api/getting-started/about-twitter-api#v2-access-level

After some googling, I found this. No authentication is needed but I can't guarantee that it will not be taken down in the future. Just provide the screen_name of any account you want. E.g.

https://cdn.syndication.twimg.com/widgets/followbutton/info.json?screen_names=binance

...which will give you something like this:

```
[
    {
        "following": false,
        "id": "877807935493033984",
        "screen_name": "binance",
        "name": "Binance",
        "protected": false,
        "followers_count": 6959348,
        "formatted_followers_count": "6.96M followers",
        "age_gated": false
    }
]
```

Comment: Still working at the beginning of Feb :-D

Comment: It does have a rate limit though I'm not sure exactly what that limit is

Comment: This is no longer working as of Feb 15, 2023. It just returns an empty response

Answer (score 2):

In Swift 4.2 and Xcode 10.1 to get twitter `followers_count`

Here you need to integrate twitter SDK into you app and follow integration details https://github.com/twitter/twitter-kit-ios

```
//This is complete url 
https://api.twitter.com/1.1/users/show.json?screen_name=screenName

func getStatusesUserTimeline(accessToken:String) {

    let userId = "109*************6"
    let twitterClient = TWTRAPIClient(userID: userId)
    twitterClient.loadUser(withID: userId) { (user, error) in
        print(userId)
        print(user ?? "Empty user")
        if user != nil {
            var request = URLRequest(url: URL(string: "https://api.twitter.com/1.1/users/show.json?screen_name=screenName")!)

            request.httpMethod = "GET"
            request.setValue("Bearer "+accessToken, forHTTPHeaderField: "Authorization")
            print(request)

            let task = URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: request) { data, response, error in guard let data = data, error == nil else { // check for fundamental networking error
                print("error=\(String(describing: error))")
                return
                }

                if let httpStatus = response as? HTTPURLResponse, httpStatus.statusCode != 200 { // check for http errors
                    print("statusCode should be 200, but is \(httpStatus.statusCode)")
                    print("response = \(String(describing: response))")
                }

                do {
                    let response = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data, options: []) as! Dictionary<String,Any>
                    print(response)
                    // print((response["statuses"] as! Array<Any>).count)

                } catch let error as NSError {
                    print(error)
                }
            }

            task.resume()

        } else {
            print(error?.localizedDescription as Any)
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: I want to get the followers list for a specific Twitter user, can you please guide me, here is the question link: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76726633/get-twitter-account-followers-using-api-and-google-apps-script

Answer (score 2):

Using Python:

```
import tweepy
twitter = tweepy.Client(bearer_token="your bearer token")
```

Single user:

```
print(twitter.get_user(username="twitter username", user_fields=["public_metrics"]).data.public_metrics['followers_count'])
```

Multiple users:

```
for i in twitter.get_users(usernames=twitterProfiles, user_fields=["public_metrics"]).data:
  print(i.public_metrics['followers_count'])
```