# Can I know how much followers I had on my twitter account in a specific date?

Tags: twitter

Im using python-twitter to retrieve information about my account using twitter-API.

Is it possible to know how much following / followers I had in a specific date ? Just like http://twittercounter.com where you can see how much followers you had on a specific date.

Thanks a lot !

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to get a count of followers from Twitter API and trendline](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4084909/how-to-get-a-count-of-followers-from-twitter-api-and-trendline)

Comment: There isn't a way to use the Twitter API and look back in history on your profile. As a workaround, you could automate a process that queries your profile each day and have the history for as long as you've been recording it.